Ubuntu 24.04 input/output error(5) when installing system
Dec 09 19:55:00 ubuntu subiquity_log.3667[7701]: rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "/tmp/tmpthw5ncq_/mount/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/gnome-42-2204_176.snap":
Input/output error (5)
Dec 09 19:55:25 ubuntu subiquity_log.3667[7701]: rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "/tmp/tmpthw5ncq_/mount/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap":
Input/output error (5)
Dec 09 19:56:08 ubuntu subiquity_log.3667[7701]: rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "/tmp/tmpthw5ncq_/mount/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/thunderbird_507.snap":
Input/output error (5)
I cannot install Ubuntu. It takes too much time and it isn't installing.

HD or SSD - Bios or Uefi boot. Single or shared system. Output of sudo fdisk -l.
